# Android Background color change

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the XML file   
    blog.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </LinearLayout>
```

.java file

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blog);
        View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.info);

        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("hallo");
        valueTV.setId(5);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
    }
```

Here i need the entire Activity to be turned white.But while compiling this program, the text written has white background.i.e "hallo" word has the white background.

Please help.

Comment: ```android:background="#FFFFFF"``` that's why your text has white background.

Comment: If you want whole activity to be white, set the custom theme for the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `LinearLayout` in the XML has the height and width set to `wrap_content`. Change this to `fill_parent` to fill the whole activity. At the moment it is just wrapping the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in your xml to

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </LinearLayout>
```